# Azure with Unity How do I create a query?

Tags: c#, database, linq, azure, unity-game-engine

I have started to use Azure and I am having a hard time finding documentation that actually works in Unity. I have the database connecting, and inserting / deleting / updating but I can't find the actual syntax to create a query or filter a database call based on Id / string etc. I see there is a 'create query' method on table but I don't see how it is actually used.

Thanks, 
Fabrizio

Comment: Do you mean a SELECT statement with a WHERE clause (to filter)? It's a bit unclear what you need.

Comment: Sorry, no I don't mean the syntax of the query but using the 'CreateQuery' method in Unity. For example, the methods available InsertAsync, DeleteAsync, UpdateAsync are working fine but I don't see how to actually create a query and then retrieve the data and the syntax used. I can get all of the data with table.ToListAsync(). Does that make sense? I also see that intellisense shows that CreateQuery is available but it doesn't take any parameters.

Comment: I think it's less clear to me now to be honest. You have other methods working successfully. I don't think those methods are specific to Unity either. Wouldn't you write a query like `SELECT UserId FROM Users WHERE UserName = 'Spoonshoe'` and then execute it with `ExecuteReader`?

Comment: Sorry I'm not articulating. So, if you look at this doc page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/writing-linq-queries-against-the-table-service       it shows some sample queries and it uses the method 'CreateQuery' which takes a parameter. But what I'm referring to is specifically inside Unity which I assume doesn't have access to every method, how would I make this call to CreateQuery() as in Unity it does not take any parameters but it's showing up in Intellisense. So i'm lookin for the full method call.

Comment: So LINQ? I am going to add those tags to your post. I don't see why the method in Unity would not allow for parameters unless all queries are only ad-hoc or something. Maybe someone else knows better!